# using C# update SQL table from a JSON

Tags: c#, sql, json, sqldatareader

I am calling a web service that outputs a `JSON` payload, the `JSON` string has *productName*, *packageId*, *webReferenceId*. When calling the web service the *productName* is passed as the query string. I am able to pass the query string and retrieve the `JSON` payload that has *productName*, *packageId*, *webReferenceId* as shown below.

***JSON:***

```
{
    "product": [
        {           
            "product": "adc",
            "pkgid": 1124245,
            "wrfid": 5387612
        }
    ]
}
```

Using the below `C#` code to retrieve the `JSON` payload.

***C#:***

```
var jsondata = new WebClient();
string prdcode = jsondata.DownloadString(new Uri(url));

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer
{
    MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
};
Rootobject ro = jss.Deserialize<Rootobject>(prdcode);
```

Now, I will have to update the `SQL` table with *packageId*, *webReferenceId* from the `JSON` output. I am reading `JSON` results into a `DataReader` but not sure how to `UPDATE` the `SQL` table.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("packageId", typeof(int)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("webReferenceId", typeof(int)));
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

foreach (var product in ro.data)
{
    dr["packageId"] = product.pkgid;
    dr["webReferenceId"] = product.wrfid;
}
```

Comment: What library are you using to access the SQL server? Entity Frameworks? Linq2SQL? Plain old System.Data.SqlClient?

Comment: Hi @Corey, Plain old System.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: Like doing things the hard way, huh? :) OK... let me play around with BulkCopy and stuff, see what I can do.

Comment: Out of interest... any reason you're using SqlClient instead of an ORM? It gets tiresome having to deal with `DataTable`s all the time, don't you find?

Comment: Hi @Corey, This is a legacy code which has fallen into my lap to support. There would be a lot of re-write. This is for a vendor application and they will be upgrading and moving to the cloud very soon.

Comment: Oh... in that case, I won't evangelize my favorite ORM to you. Answer incoming.

Answer (score 1):

The 'best' way to do this will depend on how many rows you're expecting to process. If it's only a few rows then go ahead and insert them using a series of parameterized `INSERT INTO...` commands.

For bigger lists though the [`SqlBulkCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy) object will take a `DataTable` or `IDataReader` and upload the contents in bulk to your table.

```
// abstracting the setup for brevity - you can write these :)
var source = LoadDataTable();
var connection = GetSqlConnection();

// now the bulk copy:
using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
{
    bulk.DestinationTableName = "your_table";
    bulk.WriteToServer(source);
}
```

This will attempt to dump the rows directly into the table. If there's anything different about the data types, etc. then the insert will fail with an error message that (hopefully) will explain what went wrong.

You'll have to ensure that the source data doesn't violate any constraints, like duplicating existing primary keys and such, and that it matches the format of the target table.

Depending on your use case it might help to load the data into a staging table (temporary or otherwise) and then use a `MERGE` to update the final target. This can help deal with primary key violations, etc. It also lets you do some of the ETL tasks with queries and stored procedures on the SQL server itself rather than pulling tons of data out, matching it all up and pushing it back.